# "error=13, Permission denied" error when running C compiled .cgi file in linux with Tomcat6

Tags: java, linux, cgi, tomcat6

I have enabled the CGI module in web.xml and added previleged=true in the context.xml. Placed the cgi file in the WEB-INF/cgi/ folder in my application. When trying to access the below URL I get "error=13, Permission denied" error. (http://localhost:8080/cute/cgi-bin/cutecgi.cgi)

```
 致命的: サーブレット cgi のServlet.service()が例外を投げました
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cute/WEB-INF/cgi/cutecgi.cgi" (in directory "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cute/WEB-INF/cgi"): java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet$CGIRunner.run(CGIServlet.java:1649)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet.doGet(CGIServlet.java:592)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:865)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 21 more
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the file permissions of your CGI script. Either the file cannot be accessed by the user that the Tomcat server is running as, or the file itself does not have execute permission for this user.

Try running this command to view the file permissions:

```
ls -l /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cute/WEB-INF/cgi/cutecgi.cgi
```

Comment: This is the result i got running that command                  -rw-rw-r--. 1 user001 user001 21380 Sep  6 09:41 /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cute/WEB-INF/cgi/cutecgi.cgi

Comment: yeah thanks for the info....I changed the chmod to 755 for cutecgi.cgi.I got it working now..Thank you @codebox

Comment: The cutecgi.cgi file is not executable, which explains the error. You need to add the execute permission using the chmod command, eg chmod 755 cutecgi.cgi however be careful to only grant this permission to the user which is running the tomcat server or it could lead to security issues

Comment: Now the rights is like-rwxr-xr-x. 1 user001 user001 21380 Sep  6 09:41 /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cute/WEB-INF/cgi/cutecgi.cgi

Comment: I had a similar problem with JDownloader 2 Beta in Netrunner Rolling, execute permissions were missing. solved with: sudo chmod +x /opt/JDownloader/tools/linux/ffmpeg/x64/ffmpeg